# how to use powerlevel9k in zsh to get efficient output

Tags: themes, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have installed zsh and oh my zsh in my terminal and change it using an online guide in a Ubuntu Linux derivative called Zorin OS 15.

but after installing it, I tried to use powerlevel9k theme but it didn't end up as it was shown in the guide or in any other video.

If you know the solution, please answer the question.

Thank you

[this is the result. Please check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlWAQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to install the powerline fonts so that the prompt displays correctly.

https://github.com/powerline/fonts

Answer (score 0):

Use [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/) instead. It's backward-compatible with powerlevel9k configs but much faster, easier to set up and has scores of extra features. Type `p10k configure` after installing it. Optionally, install [the recommended font](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#recommended-meslo-nerd-font-patched-for-powerlevel10k) to unlock all prompt styles.